# Calcular soma da diagonal principal de uma matriz em JavaScript (Node)

Tags: javascript, node.js, algoritmo, matriz

estou tentando calcular a diagonal principal de uma matriz em Js, alguém poderia ajudar ?

```
function calcularDiagonal(matriz) {
  let soma = 0;
  for(let i = 0; i < matriz.length; i++) {
    for(let j = 0; j < matriz.length; j++) {
      if( matriz[i] == matriz[j]) {
        soma += matriz[i];
      }
    }
  }
  return soma;
}

const matriz = [[1,2,3,4,4,4,5,5,5]];

console.log(calcularDiagonal(matriz));
```

Eu fiz assim mas está retornando um resultado errado, que é :

```
01,2,3,4,4,4,5,5,5
```

Mas deveria dar o resultado 10, se alguém poder ver o que está de errado, agradeço.

Comment: A diagonal é uma propriedade de matrizes quadradas. Não se calcula diagonal de matrizes não quadradas. A matriz em seu exemplo é uma matriz linha portanto sem diagonal.

Comment: @AugustoVasques removi a minha resposta. A do Virgilio está ótima e já lhe tinha dado `+1` :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Parece que falta conceito, então: [Matriz quadrada é um tipo especial de matriz que possui o mesmo número de linhas e o mesmo de colunas, sendo que toda matriz quadrada possui duas diagonais](https://mundoeducacao.uol.com.br/matematica/matriz-quadrada.htm): Diagonal Principal e Diagonal Secundária, exemplo:

> [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

sendo que a sua diagonal principal é: `a11 = 12, a22 = 6, a33 = 0 e a44 = 15`.

Computacionalmente um exemplo de código:

```js
const matriz = [
  [12,-8,15,6],
  [1,6,20,-9],
  [0,-4,0,-8],
  [-1,6,0,15]
];

function calculo(matriz) {
  const count = matriz.length;
  let result = 0;
  for(let i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    result += matriz[i][i];
  }
  return result;
}

console.log(calculo(matriz));
```

```html
<table border="1" width="100%">
  <tr>
    <td>12</td>
    <td>-8</td>
    <td>15</td>
    <td>6</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>6</td>
    <td>20</td>
    <td>-9</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>0</td>
    <td>-4</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td>-8</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>-1</td>
    <td>6</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td>15</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

A sua diagonal principal são os números 12, 6, 0, 15 respectivamente as posições 1,1 - 2,2 - 3,3 e 4,4 é soma é 33 como demonstrado no código essa soma só acontece em matriz quadrática, ou seja, o mesmo de número de linhas é igual o mesmo número de colunas e vice-versa (3x3, 4x4, `etc`);

Comment: Atenção que numa matriz rectangular `matriz[i][i]` vai ter um parametro `undefined`

Comment: @Sergio uma matriz retangular não é uma matriz quadrada como dito na pergunta, ou seja, como já explicado tem que ter o mesmo número de colunas igual o número de linhas e retangular não se enquadra

Comment: @Sergio: *estou tentando calcular a diagonal principal de uma matriz em Js* só matriz quadrada tem isso.

Comment: Pessoal, me confundi e era apenas somar com matriz[i][j], com um array em js sendo const matriz = [[1,2,3],[4,4,4],[5,5,5]];

Comment: Eu queria somar uma matriz quadrada e estava definindo ela errada em JS, obrigado :)

Comment: Já corrigi, tinha aceitado a errada :)

Comment: Virgilio, ok não tinha reparado nesse detalhe! `+1` @
AugustoVasques a minha resposta não estava errada, somente é mais generalista :)